# Recenter Google Map when app is returned to foreground using Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google Maps iOS SDK for an application that I am working on. I now need to recenter the map on the users current location when the application is returned to the foreground or when the user comes back to the map view. I have searched and searched and tried a few things however, nothing has worked.

I have tried placing code in the "didUpdateLocations" handler of the CoreLocation stack, but this didn't work. At the same time, the viewWillAppear function is not called when the application is brought back into the foreground, so that didn't work either.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {        
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (manager.location!.coordinate.latitude), longitude: (manager.location!.coordinate.longitude), zoom: 16.0)
    self.mapView?.animate(to: camera)
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try using the NotificationCenter? add the observer in the view controller with the map and then post the notification in the AppDelegate in applicationDidBecomeActive.
(I can't post comments due to my reputation)